# Expo build:android producing apk with uncaught error

Tags: react-native, expo

After building expo android and producing an apk, the apk when open-- displays an uncaught error that is not shown on the development using expo app but only shows on the produced apk.

I already tried doing `expo start`, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>, then `expo build:android`. Not even in building the apk shows errors.

Here's the screenshot of the apk uncaught error:

[image]

[Uncaught Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5r9x.jpg)

Comment: Do you have STANDARD_EVENT_ADD_TO_CART in your code? If you do, please post the code that refers to it.

Comment: No I don't have @Yossi, As far as I know, STANDARD_EVENT_ADD_TO_CART is from react-native-branch but I'm not sure where it fails..

Comment: Sorry, no idea, then.
I see that there are search results with it. Perhaps you will find something there:

https://www.google.com/search?q=error+%22STANDARD_EVENT_ADD_TO_CART%22

Comment: you need to add and link the RNBranch SDK directly in Xcode

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's been changes `expo build:android` because of google play privacy policies. Branch module was removed from the android build.

Found this link that Expo posted that will give us workaround solution for awhile... I'm currently using ExpoKit

[Changes to Expo Branch Support](https://blog.expo.io/changes-to-expo-branch-support-d002c4bc564e)

[Link to other solutions](https://forums.expo.io/t/expo-build-android-produces-apk-with-uncaught-error/21956)